# Passing a variable to an include

Tags: templating, group, include

I have a category listing template where I'm having trouble passing in some variables.

top of the template I have this snippet where I'll set the channel and category field name based on the segment

```
{% set segment = craft.request.segment(1) %}

{# set channel based on segment_1 #}
{% if segment == "business-intel" %}
    {% set channelName = "businessIntel" %}
    {% set categoryName = "businessIntelCategories" %}
{% elseif segment == "foo" %}
    {# do nothing #}
{% endif %}
{# end set channel #}
```

Then further down the template I have this:

```
{% include ('_includes/cat_sub_with_article') with { 'categoryName' : categoryName } %}
```

And then the included template looks like this:

```
 {% for category, catEntries in entries | group('categoryName.first().title') %}
    <h2>{{ category }}</h2>


    {% set featuredThumb = {
        mode: 'crop',
        width: 370,
        height: 168,
        quality: 90,
        position: 'top-center'
      } %}

    <div class="article-cards">
        {% for entry in catEntries %}
        <div class="article-card__wrapper">
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="article-card">

                {% set image = entry.featuredImage.first() %}

                <span class="article-card__image">
                    <img src="{{ image.url(featuredThumb) }}" />
                </span>
                <span class="article-card__text">
                    <span class="article-card__category">{{ entry.postDate.format('M d, Y') }}</span>
                    <h3 class="article-card__title">{{ entry.title }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ entry.featuredSummary }}</p>
                    <p><span class="link--green" href="{{ entry.url }}">Learn More</span></p>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div><!-- /.article-cards -->
 {% endfor %}
```

If I hardcode the category field name into line 1 of the above block everything works. However if I try to use the passed varialbe. I get this error, which I don't know how to fix:

> Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure
>   named "categoryName".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the variable that your are passing in to your include to a string. And in your include you try to access it like an object.

The variable which you’re passing in to your include is set to a string `'businessIntelCategories'`. And in your include you try access a object property dynamically using that string which doesn’t work.

Use this code instead.

```
{% set entriesGrouped = entries|group('{ object[categoryName].first().title }') %}
```

Here’s an attempt to explain the syntax.

First you should have a look at the Craft documentation for [Dynamic Entry Titles](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles). You see that you can dynamically generate titles with a normal Twig template `{{ object.property }}` or a special shortcut syntax `{property}`.

The `group` filter uses the same internal functionality to render the string that you pass in as a filter argument `group('my twig template string')`. The syntax has to be a bit different though, because `group` already adds one pair of curly braces for you.

So usually you echo the title property like so

```
{{ object.title }}
```

and in the context of the `group` filter you can do both of the following.

```
{% set entriesGrouped = entries|group('title') %}

{% set entriesGrouped = entries|group('{ object.title }') %}
```

The first syntax, which uses the shortcut syntax, is documented and fine for most cases. But you can’t use it if you need to do something a bit more advanced, like using a ternary operator or in your case access the `object` object differently.

So to wrap this up, the syntax for `group('{ object[categoryName].first().title }')` is confusing. But what it does is to render the following Twig code for each element of your array of entries (each entry is passed in as the variable `object`).

```
{{ object[categoryName].first().title }}
```

If you don’t like the `object['propertyName']` syntax, you can use the [`attribute`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/functions/attribute.html) function instead.

```
{{ attribute(object, categoryName).first().title }}
```

Comment: That worked but I don't understand why.